# What is the main site for Area51

Tags: support, area-51

Today I tried to delete my account on AREA51 but was unable to do so because

> this operation cannot be performed on a meta site; please continue on the main site.

[image]

I have tried

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/ and
http://area51.stackexchange.com/ (the contact in the footer redirects to discuss... )

What is the main site for AREA51 where I can delete my profile?

Comment: What happened in Area51, stays in Area51...

Comment: And it also mentions the problem you've encountered :)

Comment: @nicael kinda, sorta, maybe. If you read the possible dupe carefully the messages that the OP got are different to the ones I got. The current instructions on how to delete an account are also different (they don't for example instruct me to put anything in my profile http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). So it seems that some work was done, it may be incomplete (6-8 weeks still to pass) or a bug. I'm sure we'll find out.

Comment: The main site is area51.stackexchange.com . Area 51 Discussions, the one in your screenshot, is Area 51's meta.

Comment: @S.L.Barth As I said in the text I went to area51.stackexchange.com and clicked on the Contact Us in the footer, it redirects to discuss...